# Null coalescing string and conditional string via logical OR-operator results in number

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, null-coalescing, logical-or

Null coalescing by `OR`ing a string (via `PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]]` where `priorityNum` is input) and a string (via conditional `Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum) ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low`) should output a string yet outputs a number (matching the input). Why does this happen?

This could be a js quirk but unsure why the output is a number as testing shows coalescing should be between 2 strings to output a string:

```js
const PRIORITIES = {
    high: 'HIGH',
    low: 'LOW',
};
const NUM_TO_PRIORITY = {
    0: 'high',
    1: 'low',
};
const priorityNum = 0;
console.log(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]]); // "HIGH"
console.log(Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum)); // false
console.log("HIGH" || false) // "HIGH" <- Expected output

// Based on the above code, the following code should output "HIGH" yet outputs 0, why does this happen?
console.log(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]] || Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum) ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low);
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice, added a snippet in case it helps others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` has higher [`operator precedence`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `?`, so your code is evaluated as

```
(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]] || Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum))  ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low
```

```js
const PRIORITIES = {
    high: 'HIGH',
    low: 'LOW',
};
const NUM_TO_PRIORITY = {
    0: 'high',
    1: 'low',
};
const priorityNum = 0;
console.log(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]]); // "HIGH"
console.log(Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum)); // false
// "HIGH" || false // "HIGH" <- Expected output

// Based on the above code, the following code should output "HIGH" yet outputs 0, why does this happen?
console.log(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]] || Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum) ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low);
```

Comment: agreed that `||` has higher precedence but shouldn't that mean it becomes  `(PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]] || Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum))` which resolves to `"HIGH" || false` which should output `"HIGH"`?

Comment: @surajs02 no which resolves further to "HIGH" ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low and finally resolves down to 0

Comment: sorry, didn't see the brackets added, `?` resolving after `||`  makes sense, thanks, will accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer, it is due to operator precedence.

```
valOne || valTwo ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low;
```

is the same as:

```
(valOne || valTwo) ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low;
```

but you wanted:

```
valOne || (valTwo ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low);
```

Since most don't have the precedence memorized for 20+ operators, avoid these mistakes by either using more parentheses (as seen above) or more variables:

```
const PRIORITIES = {
    high: 'HIGH',
    low: 'LOW',
};
const NUM_TO_PRIORITY = {
    0: 'high',
    1: 'low',
};
const priorityNum = 0;

const priority = PRIORITIES[NUM_TO_PRIORITY[priorityNum]]
const otherVal = Object.values(PRIORITIES).includes(priorityNum) ? priorityNum : PRIORITIES.low

priority || otherVal; // "HIGH"
```

Comment: for `Since most don't have the precedence memorized for 20+ ...` +1

Comment: brackets was useful, +1 for `avoid these problems by ...` :)